# Set RichEditBox to empty

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

I have a richeditbox whose contents can be filled in by the user
XAML:

```
<RichEditBox
      x:Name="jawabBox"
      FontWeight="SemiBold"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Background="#FFDFF6EE"
      Foreground="Black"
      CornerRadius="15,15,15,15" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" PlaceholderText="Jawaban"/>
```

I have a problem, namely: when the user has filled in the richeditbox, then clicks the next button, then I want to set the next richeditbox to empty, but it doesn't work.

Code when setting richeditbox to empty:

```
string textValue = string.Empty;
jawabBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out textValue);
```

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use [ITextDocument.SetText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.settext?view=winrt-22621) to set your richeditbox to empty.

```
jawabBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, string.Empty);
```